# jQuery using .html() to get the HTML including the target element?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a table and I would like to assign the HTML as a string variable. How can I do it so that the opening/closing `table` tags are included in the string? I know I could just wrap the table in a container and get the HTML of the container, but wondering if there's a solution without modifying the layout.

```js
$(function() {
  // want the following variable to include open/closing table tags
  var tableHTML = $('table').html();
  
  alert(tableHTML);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You can use clone() method to achieve that. Also pure javascript provide a method of any container dom object dom.outerHTML which method will return html including target element.

Answer (score 1):

Using `outerHTML`

```js
$(function() {
  // want the following variable to include open/closing table tags
  var tableHTML = $('table')[0].outerHTML;

  console.log(tableHTML);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```js
$(function() {
  // want the following variable to include open/closing table tags
  var tableHTML = $('table').prop('outerHTML')
  
  alert(tableHTML);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```